# laravel orm update document

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been trying to update a document using laravel ORM but getting exception stating a `unknown column updated_at`.

This column is not in database table, and neither have I mentioned in the query.

```
$foo = ProductMatchUnmatchHistory::where('product_match_unmatches_id', $pmu->id)
                    ->update(['is_latest'=>0]);
```

`ProductMatchUnmatchHistory` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'product_match_unmatches_id',
    'human_verdict',
    'ai_result',
    'updated_on',
    'updated_by',
    'is_latest'
];
```

The table has the same columns as in `$fillable` array, with additional `id` primary key.

Here's the exception message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `product_match_unmatch_histories` set `is_latest` = 0, `updated_at` = 2019-11-20 12:20:02 where `product_match_unmatches_id` = 1759)
```

I have no clue from where the `updated_at` column is added to the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `updated_at` and `created_at` fields from Laravel's Eloquent models, edit your `ProductMatchUnmatchHistory.php` model and set `$timestamps = false`.

```
class ProductMatchUnmatchHistory extends Model
{
    //....
    $timestamps = false;
    //....
}
```

#### Additional Info

Laravel Models automatically set a `created_at` field when an entry is created and update the `updated_at` column when you do any changes to a row. This is handled through the `$timestamps` field on the model. If set to `true`, which is default, laravel will assume that your models have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

In most cases this is pretty helpful. You can easily add these fields in your migration by just adding `$table->timestamps();`.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions
(under Timestamps)

Answer (score 1):

*please change*

you must define table name

```
protected $table = 'your table name';

protected $fillable = [
    'product_match_unmatches_id',
    'human_verdict',
    'ai_result',
    'updated_on',
    'updated_by',
    'is_latest'
];
$timestamps = false;
```

Comment: `$timestamps=false` worked for me.

Comment: Ok great please select this answer as Helpful thank you.@Azima

Answer (score 0):

First please check in your table updated_at exist? because sql error say column not found

Comment: no.. there's no updated_at. Is this a mandatory field?

Answer (score 0):

@Azima you should added the column in your table otherwise you will get this error, because eloquent updating that column and its not present in table or you can `$timestamps=false` in your Model